# get value from firestore take time

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

The problem is that the value from the database is updated after the response to google action is finished , i have tried couple of option to make the function to wait for the value to update, but it doesn't work, 
i need to execute twice to get the right value[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVpLm.jpg)

```js
function operation(callback) {
  dialogflowAgentDoc.doc(format).get()
  .then(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data().Url);
      Url = doc.data().Url;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
    callback(Url);
}

app.intent("Default Welcome Intent", conv => {
   new GetFormat();
   console.log("GetFormat Started");
   new operation(function(Url) {
    console.log("Ask Started");
        conv.ask(
 new SimpleResponse({
        speech: "Playing Gallay Tzahal",
        text: "Playing Gallay Tzahal"
    }),
  new MediaObject({
        name: 'Gallay Tzahal News',
        url: Url,
        description: "text",
        icon: new Image({
            url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/he/thumb/3/30/GaltzLogo.svg/150px-GaltzLogo.svg.png',
            alt: 'Media icon',
        }),
    })
 );
   });
   conv.ask(suggestions3);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading data from the cloud takes take. To prevent blocking your app while waiting for that data, the Firestore (and most modern web APIs) load the data asynchronously and then call a function you pass into `then()` when the data is available.

This means that code that needs the data from Firestore must be *inside* the `then()` callback, which gets called when the data is available. So:

```
function operation(callback) {
  dialogflowAgentDoc.doc(format).get()
  .then(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data().Url);
      Url = doc.data().Url;
      callback(Url);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
}
```

Comment: now i have an error "Error getting documents Error: Response has already been sent. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?"

Comment: The same as in my answer, your `conv.ask(suggestions3);` needs to be **inside** the callback function. So: move it one line up. :)